# How to prevent trigger from updating the timestamp on a column in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I have a table which has a column on which I have set a trigger to update the timestamp when there is an update on the row

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
    id NUMBER NOT NULL,
    sid VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    stext VARCHAR(10),
    tid VARCHAR(10),
    ttext VARCHAR(10),
    last_updated TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    CONSTRAINT unique PRIMARY KEY (id) ENABLE
);

CREATE OR REPLACE trigger last_updated_trigger
  BEFORE UPDATE ON mytable
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    select systimestamp into :new.last_updated from dual;
END;
/
```

However, when certain SQLs are executed on the table, I do NOT want the 'last_updated' column to be updated. For instance, when the below SQL updates this table, I do **NOT** want the trigger to kick in. I need the column to retain the last_updated value so that my other queries do not get messed up. However, when other SQLs do updates on the data, I want the column to be updated.

Any ideas on how this could be done?

```
MERGE INTO mytable
USING dual
ON (id = ?)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET
        stext = case when sid = ? then ? else stext end,
        ttext = case when tid = ? then ? else ttext end
```

Comment: Either you want the value set in a trigger or you do not.  Perhaps you should just set the value manually and remove the trigger.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. Is there any way I can modify the trigger so that I can it only updates the column if a value is not supplied by the SQL and/or modify the SQL to retain the old value of the column?

Comment: Putting on my  IT Auditor hat. You just failed the audit. You have a column which indicates when an action took place on a row, but  sometimes id does not indicate that at all. So what does the column "last_updated" actually mean.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily keep a supplied value and only insert the current time if it is not supplied:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE trigger last_updated_trigger
  BEFORE UPDATE ON mytable
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    :new.last_updated := coalesce(:new.last_updated, systimestamp);
END;
```

Comment: Thanks, @Barbaros. Will try it. Also, any idea how to modify the merge sql posted in my question to retain the last_updated timestamp?

Comment: Hi @Barbaros, I tried the above trigger, but now it is not updating the last_updated column even if a value is not supplied by the sql?

Comment: Hi dear @Jared, I didn't reply, just edited the existing style :) for simplicity ...

Comment: Hi @BarbarosÖzhan, FYI, the above trigger is not working for me. The new trigger definition completely stopped updating the 'last_updated' field.

Comment: @Jared . . . This trigger should be updating `last_updated`, with _some_ value.

Comment: well, I've added an answer that you can check it out @Jared

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to fire trigger when you update STEXT or TTEXT columns please try this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE trigger last_updated_trigger
  BEFORE UPDATE ON mytable
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    if (not updating('stext') and not updating('ttext')) then
       :new.last_updated := systimestamp;
    end if;
END;
```

Thanks

Comment: Thanks @gogocho. But there are other SQLs which update the stext and ttext which need to update 'last_updated'

Answer (score 0):

You can put that specific SQL Statement into a PROCEDURE in which the module info is updated for the concerned application(*always call this statement from this procedure only*) such as

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Merge_Text AS
BEGIN
  DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.SET_MODULE($$plsql_unit,null);
  MERGE INTO mytable
  USING dual
      ON (id = ?)
  WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET
        stext = case when sid = ? then ? else stext end,
        ttext = case when tid = ? then ? else ttext end;
END;
/
```

and then distinguish this caller module within the trigger such as

```
CREATE OR REPLACE trigger last_updated_trigger
  BEFORE UPDATE ON mytable
  FOR EACH ROW
  v_module  VARCHAR2(80);
  v_action  VARCHAR2(80);  
BEGIN
  DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.READ_MODULE(v_module, v_action);
 IF v_module != 'MERGE_TEXT' THEN
  :new.last_updated  := systimestamp;
 END IF;
END;
/
```

Comment: Thank you @Barbaros. However, I went for a PreparedStatement as PreparedStatements can be batched on the client side, but CallableStatements can't be batched. I will need to use Collections, Records and I haven't found any decent JDBC code online which does bulk operations, so that I can use CallableStatements!